# Pop-up close and parent window refresh not working

Tags: javascript

I can't get this working.

Here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function close()  {                                        
        window.opener.location.reload();
        self.close();                       
     }  
</script>
    <hr />
    <h6>
        Thank you for uploading! Click <a style="color:black;" href="#" onclick="close();">here</a> to continue.

    </h6>
            <br />       
    <hr />
```

Also, when I ran Firebug profiler, it didn't show any calls to onclick or close functions. Strange!

Help!

Comment: should you use a different name for your function? 'close' is already defined in the global space?

Comment: thanks for commenting ... that was one of the problem ... you should have answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.close()` is going to call the (presumably undefined)  `close` method on the `A` tag.
To close the pop up window, you need to call `window.close()`.